# there is no line here to end how to introduce space of a line

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

I am having following code section

```
Security Centre uses following technologies
\newline

\subsection{Intelligent threat intelligence} 
\newline It looks for bad actors by using
```

I get error there is no line here to end.
I want to know how can I introduce gap of a line in my pages so that I can generated things with space in between text.I know if in microsoft word I press enter key it generates a new line I want something similar in this.

Comment: Do you want a small vertical white space between subsequent paragraphs of text? Or do you want to increase the spacing between section titles and the following text? Please clarify. Please also make your code complete (documentclass, packages,...)

Comment: You don't and in Word you shouldn't. Don't mix design and contents. If you need more spaces around `\subsection` then learn to customize `\subsection`. IMO a new user should **never** mess with `\newline` as they do not know how to use it (it shopuld hardly ever be used). And as a novice user you should be writing documents not playing/changing designs, that is just a waste of time.

Comment: I want more spacing between some paragraphs. I am comfortable with Microsoft word but I do not know how it works in latex I press enter key and there I am used to get desired space. I do not understand this there is a section which reads some thing then there are some bullet points items and then some paragraph is there then some image is there due to improper line meaning I want a gap of horizontal line in between some thing to start.

Comment: you should almost never need `\newline` or `\\ ` in a document. If you want a style with vertical space between paragraphs that should be specified one in the document preamble, eg add `\usepackage{parskip}`

Comment: (i) LaTeX is not a Word ... (ii) in the case that between all paragraphs you like more space,  in preamble add `\setlength\parskip{<length>}`, (iii) if you like add only at some place vertical space, after empty line add `\vspace{<lenght>   where `<lenfght>` is desired space. In cases that you like to have more space after `section` redefine `\section` definition (how to do this, ask a new question or search this site). Please read some introductory text as https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.